# Why did git push failed? error: failed to push some refs to

Tags: git, github

My previous step was

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/MilenkoM/ex1microhydra.git

git remote -v
```

shows

```
origin  https://github.com/MilenkoM/ex1microhydra.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/MilenkoM/ex1microhydra.git (push)
```

If I go for

```
git push origin master
```

then I got error

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/MilenkoM/ex1microhydra.git'
```

Why?
Git log shows

```
commit 0e9a31ff7c1fb1d0bb56e8ad5a359f92666be6a9 (HEAD -> mybranch)
Date:   Wed Dec 18 17:12:21 2019 +0100

     Changes to be committed:
            new file:   index.js
            new file:   package.json
```

I followed the advice from Loi and eftshift,and tried this

```
git checkout master

Switched to branch 'master'
```

It doesn't work either

```
git push origin mybranch:master
```

Says

```
To https://github.com/MilenkoM/ex1microhydra.git
 ! [rejected]        mybranch -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/MilenkoM/ex1microhydra.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I am new to git,what are these fast-forwards?

```
 git show-ref
8ef0e288bb2ab7c42ebc37b018fcb08a73073c2e refs/heads/master
0e9a31ff7c1fb1d0bb56e8ad5a359f92666be6a9 refs/heads/mybranch
097e48b3fd8f87f90f19872fc788ea2f0bb433cc refs/remotes/origin/master
```

I should go for pull,but pull what?

Comment: Try `git checkout -b "master"`  before `push` to see if it works *(of course also merge the necessary changes from your `mybranch` before `push`)*

Comment: Switched to a new branch 'master'

Comment: Try the answer below, it sounds promising *(remember `git checkout mybranch` again first)*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+src+refspec+master+does+not+match+any

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Comment: I am struggling to understand what should I pull. git pull ? Will make edit.

Comment: @phd Please,take a look at my edit.

Comment: *hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.* Well, why not look at the referenced docs? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---ff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't have a local branch called *master*. If you want to push your *mybrancy* branch into remote master, you do it like this:

```
git push origin mybranch:master
```